# How do I update data inside a stringified JSON object in SQL?

Tags: json, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

So I have three databases - an Oracle one, SQL Server one, and a Postgres one. I have a table that has two columns: `name`, and `value`, both are texts. The value is a stringified JSON object. I need to update the nested value.

This is what I currently have:

```
name: 'MobilePlatform', 
value:
    '{
       "iosSupported":true,
       "androidSupported":false,
    }'
```

I want to add `{"enableTwoFactorAuth": false}` into it.

Comment: As you won't find a single statement that will run on all three DBMS, please ask one question per database.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you should be able to do this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET MobilePlatform = jsonb_set(MobilePlatform::jsonb, '{MobilePlatform,enableTwoFactorAuth}', 'false');
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Postgres**, the plain [concatenation operator `||` for `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) could do it:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    value = value::jsonb || '{"enableTwoFactorAuth":false}'::jsonb
WHERE  name  = 'MobilePlatform';
```

If a top-level key `"enableTwoFactorAuth"` already exists, it is replaced. So it's an "upsert" really.

Or use [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) for manipulating nested values.

The cast back to `text` works implicitly as assignment cast. (Results in standard format; any insignificant whitespace is removed effectively.)

If the content is valid JSON, the storage type should be `json` to begin with. In Postges, [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) would be preferable as it's easier to manipulate, but that's not directly portable to the other two RDBMS mentioned.

(Or, possibly, a normalized design without JSON altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

Two of the databases you are using support JSON data type, so it doesn't make sense to have them as stringified JSON object in a Text column.

Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/json-in-oracle-database.html

PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Apart from these, MSSQL Server also provides methods to work with JSON data type.

MS SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Using a JSON type column in any of the above databases would enable you to use their JSON functions to perform the tasks that you are looking for.

If you've to use Text only then you can use `replace` to add the key-value pair at the end of your JSON

```
update dataTable set value = REPLACE(value, '}',",\"enableTwoFactorAuth\": false}") where name = 'MobilePlatform'
```

Here `dataTable` is the name of table.

The cleaner and less riskier way would be connect to db using the application and use JSON methods such as `JSON.parse` in Javascript and `JSON.loads` in Python. This would give you the JSON object (dictionary in case of Python) to work on. You can look for similar methods in other languages as well.

But i would suggest, if possible use JSON columns instead of Text to store the JSON value wherever possible.

Comment: SQL Server does *not* have a JSON data type. The documentation you link to is about working with JSON data; it does not state anywhere that there is a JSON data type.

Comment: @Larnu updated my reply. Thanks for pointing it out. From the document it would look like there is a JSON data type, but as you mentioned, it is not mentioned anywhere that JSON as a data type is supported anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For ORACLE 21

```
update mytable
set json_col = json_transform(
    json_col,
    INSERT '$.value.enableTwoFactorAuth' = 'false'
)
where json_exists(json_col, '$?(@.name == "MobilePlatform")')
;
```

With json_col being JSON or VARCHAR2|CLOB column with IS JSON constraint.

(but must be JSON if you want a multivalue index on json_value.name:

```
create multivalue index ix_json_col_name on mytable t ( t.json_col.name.string() );
```

)